# Automatically cycle through list of pictures

Tags: python, kivy

I have been trying to code up a simple picture viewer. Python on the backend and Kivy for the GUI.

My aim is to have 3 buttons, cycle forward, backwards and auto cycle through.

I can manually navigate back and forward through the pics but I'm struggling to get the auto cycle to work.

With the code as is, it will cycle to the next pic but then the `Clock.schedule.interval` at the top of the `auto_pic` definition causes an attribute error and crashes.

Can anyone help me out with getting the auto button to cycle through the pics?

Python side:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import os
from kivy.clock import Clock


class SlideScreen01(Screen):

    pic_path = ""
    pic_list_fwrd = []
    pic_list_bkwrd = []

    def on_enter(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.build_pics, 0)

    def build_pics(self, timeout):

        path01 = os.getcwd()
        path02 = path01.replace("\\", "/")
        pic_path01 = f"{path02}/pics/"
        pic_path02 = os.listdir(pic_path01)
        SlideScreen01.pic_path = pic_path01
        SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd = pic_path02
        # print(SlideScreen01.pic_list01)

        try:
            self.ids.piclayouti.clear_widgets()
            pic_layout = Builder.load_string(f"""
BoxLayout:
    Image:
        source: '{SlideScreen01.pic_path}{SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0]}'

""")
            self.ids.piclayouti.add_widget(pic_layout)
            print(SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd)

        except IndexError:
            print("thats all folks")

    def pics_forward(self):

        try:
            SlideScreen01.pic_list_bkwrd.insert(0, SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0])
            SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd.remove(SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0])

            self.ids.piclayouti.clear_widgets()
            pic_layout = Builder.load_string(f"""
BoxLayout:
    Image:
        source: '{SlideScreen01.pic_path}{SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0]}'

""")
            self.ids.piclayouti.add_widget(pic_layout)

            print(SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd)
            print(SlideScreen01.pic_list_bkwrd)

        except IndexError:
            print("forward")

    def pics_back(self):

        try:
            SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd.insert(0, SlideScreen01.pic_list_bkwrd[0])
            SlideScreen01.pic_list_bkwrd.remove(SlideScreen01.pic_list_bkwrd[0])

            self.ids.piclayouti.clear_widgets()
            pic_layout = Builder.load_string(f"""
BoxLayout:
    Image:
        source: '{SlideScreen01.pic_path}{SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0]}'

""")
            self.ids.piclayouti.add_widget(pic_layout)

            print(SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd)
            print(SlideScreen01.pic_list_bkwrd)

        except IndexError:
            print("back")

    def auto_pic(self):

        Clock.schedule_interval(SlideScreen01.auto_pic, 2)
        try:
            SlideScreen01.pic_list_bkwrd.insert(0, SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0])
            SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd.remove(SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0])

            self.ids.piclayouti.clear_widgets()
            pic_layout = Builder.load_string(f"""
BoxLayout:
    Image:
        source: '{SlideScreen01.pic_path}{SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0]}'

""")
            self.ids.piclayouti.add_widget(pic_layout)

            print(SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0])

        except IndexError:
            print("auto")


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Slide_ShowApp(MDApp):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Slide_ShowApp().run()
```

and the Kivy code:

```
WindowManager:
    SlideScreen01:

<SlideScreen01>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            id: piclayouti
            orientation: "horizontal"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1,None
            height: 75
            padding: 5
            spacing: 5

            Button:
                text: "Back"
                on_release: root.pics_back()

            Button:
                text: "auto"
                on_release: root.auto_pic()

            Button:
                text: "Forward"
                on_release: root.pics_forward()
```

EDIT

I figured it out after more research into kivy clock -

```
    def auto_pic(self, *args):

        try:
            SlideScreen01.pic_list_bkwrd.insert(0, SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0])
            SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd.remove(SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0])

            self.ids.piclayouti.clear_widgets()
            pic_layout = Builder.load_string(f"""
BoxLayout:
    Image:
        source: '{SlideScreen01.pic_path}{SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0]}'

""")
            self.ids.piclayouti.add_widget(pic_layout)

            print(SlideScreen01.pic_list_fwrd[0])

        except IndexError:
            print("auto")
            self.gogoauto.cancel()
            SlideScreen01.auto_stat = False

    def auto_pic02(self):
        self.gogoauto = Clock.schedule_interval(self.auto_pic, 1.5)
        SlideScreen01.auto_stat = True
```

the above reworked auto_pic now cycles through the list as intended :D